# Retrieve pdf file stream from server

Tags: java, angularjs, pdf, inputstream, filereader

By following this link  [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/Tfv2ZA5yfatuoX6bazX9?p=preview) . I want to show pdf file in new window, but I want to read the pdf file from server

My service code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/retrievePDFFile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
InputStream retrievePDFFile() throws FileNotFoundException
{
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("/resources/AngularJS 2013.pdf");
    return inputStream;
}
```

My angular controller

```
$http({
    method : "GET",
    url : "/service/retrievePDFFile"
}).success(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}).error(function(data, status) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

I got the pdf input stream from server like this..

How to read this, and open as a PDF file in new tab or window..

Thanks

[image: PDF INPUT STREAM]

Comment: I am not sure what error you are getting. When I clicked on `This Doesn't Work` button, I got a popup-blocking warning in Chrome. And when I allowed pop-ups, it opened and showed the file correctly. Have you checked this?

Comment: In that plunker they are calling pdf file url directly, In my case I'm getting pdf stream from server.. I updated my post just now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of searching I achieved the goal by little bit change in my controller code

```
$http.get('/retrievePDFFiles', {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
       .success(function (data) {
           var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
           var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
           window.open(fileURL);
    });
```